How can I determine the total mixed variable required to reach to a specific mean?
To maintain a population (neither increase nor decrease) the average child per woman needs to be $2.1$.
I want to work out, for every woman that has $2$ children, how many need to have $3$ children, so that the average is $\geq 2.1$ per woman. I want to be able to calculate for other numbers too e.g. for every woman that has $2$ children how many need to have $x$ children, or for an average of $2.3$ per woman, how many need to have $x$ if $y$ women have $z$.
Apologies for the poor quality title, I'm not sure how to word it to be interesting and specific about what I was after. If anyone's interested the context in which this arose was a discussion regarding immigration and population replenishment rates.

Do you have any ideas or attempts? Generally questions asked without any attempts are prone to closed, so I highly suggest you add some of your ideas!
